# Access doesn't respond during a long execution of VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, freeze

I have a database with VBA code execution that takes more than a minute.
The execution continues until the end (the result is correct) but during the execution the display freezes and a message appears warning that Access is not responding and asks if I want to close it.

I assumed that the VBA is run in a separate process from Access and I tried to insert a mask on which I display progress messages, but nothing has changed: the display of the mask is frozen and only at the end of the execution all appear progress messages.

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: Share your code. Usually, you can either execute it asynchronously or insert `DoEvents` in a loop to keep Access from locking up

Comment: VBA runs single-threaded, on the main/UI thread (of the host process, yes) - if it's locked up, everything is locked up =)

Comment: I'd love to see how one can execute VBA code async.

Comment: @Erik A 
I cannot share because it is some k lines.

What do you mean with "insert DoEvents"?

Comment: @Erik A
Thank you for your suggestion!
I didn't know the statement DoEvents.

Comment: @KostasK. Executing _all_ code asynchronously is hard and can require a surrogate process (often VBS), but most long-running tasks, such as queries (ADO + adAsyncExecute), web crawling (IE automation, WinHTTP, MSXML), file operations (WinAPI) can be executed asynchronously without much trouble.

Comment: @Erik A Thanks for clarifying Erik.